# Google app engine and axios post request

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, post, https, axios

I have app engine web service deployed. I have suddenly found, once clicked service name (default) link in services section of app engine, it redirects me from https://myapp-api.appspot.com/ to https://version-1-dot-myapp-api.appspot-preview.com/.

Having client application using axios node js lib (running on http), i found it giving errors trying to do POST request from client (http) to myapp (https). My app does support accepting ajax calls setting Allow-Control-Allow-Origin header. GET requests work fine.

POST request gives: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): Error: Request failed with status code 400

If i replace API url from the original one to https://version-1-dot-myapp-api.appspot-preview.com/, it works.

Any idea why? What am i doing wrong? Should i permanently replace URL to preview one? Why POST request for short URL throws an exception?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091215/automatic-redirection-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this confirmed by Google support. Preview are the url`s of services running in a new - flex environment.