# Automatic redirection google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname

I've configured my google app engine with a custom url. I added a new cname entry in my dns provided which look like this:

```
app CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

Every time I enter the url `app.website.com`, I get automatically redirected to the preview url `https://20161211t143424-dot-dfsf-151819.appspot-preview.com`. This is really annoying, how can I use my app in my custom url? Do I need to use a https?

You can see the behaviour here :  http://app.e-writer.io/

Comment: Are you using "env: flex" in your `app.yaml`?

Comment: yes. it was the recommend choice.. In addition, I would like to use python3.

Comment: @GiuseppePes I have a similar problem (www.carullo.me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235873/own-domain-redirected-to-appspot-preview-com) and I've noticed that your seems to be fixed. How did you solve it?

Comment: @ghego1 If you fill in the contact form linked in the chosen answer below you will likely receive an email from google (for the provided email address) with any questions about the configuration. Be sure to check that email soon after filling out the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the default behaviour for the (new) flexible environment these days. From [Domain update](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#domain_update) (emphasis mine):

> Traffic is now served from the `appspot-preview.com` domain instead of
>   the `appspot.com` domain. All traffic from the App Engine flexible
>   environment will be automatically redirected to the new domain. All
>   App Engine Standard traffic will continue to be through `appspot.com`.
>   When the App Engine flexible environment is generally available (GA),
>   users will be able to use the `appspot.com` or `appspot-preview.com`
>   domains for routing traffic.
>
> **For users who want to use the latest App Engine Flexible release with
>   a custom domain, please fill out [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/gae_flex_custom_domain) to contact us.**

Looks like you have to contact them using the above referenced form.

You *might* be able to switch to the previous flexible env version (i.e. using `vm:true` in the `app.yaml`). But documentation for that may be scarce now and I'm not even sure if it'll allow the custom domain to work (I didn't use any of the flex env yet, so this is just a theory).

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is ridiculous in my point of view. I am thinking to move everything to amazon. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you think I can migrate my flex environment to standard?

Comment: The standard env is more mature, but it's also more restrictive. It's a PaaS, it requires a different state of mind than "a VM". Migrating may or may not require a significant effort, depending on your app. If you look at it from a reverse migration prospective this may give you an idea: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating

Comment: Please note that according to this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ , flexible environment is not yet suitable for production use.