# app engine routes requests to version-dot-project-dot-appspot-preview.com

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am deploying a nodejs runtime to app-engine using

```
npm run deploy 
  which is configured to run
gcloud app deploy
```

the app.yaml looks like this

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

gcloud configuration list

```
Your active configuration is: [default]    
[core]
account = ~~~~~~~@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = group-coms
```

after a successful deploy it says

```
Deployed service [default] to [https://group-coms.appspot.com]
```

but when I navigate there, the request is redirected to

```
https://20161216t133707-dot-group-coms.appspot-preview.com/
```

Is that expected behavior? 
Have I fiddled with some settings to make that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic redirection google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091215/automatic-redirection-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Apps deployed to the (new) flexible environment **are now served on the appspot-preview.com domain by design**. see this answer [Automatic redirection google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091215/automatic-redirection-google-app-engine)