# App Engine Custom Domain Always Direct To appspot

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a website in app engine that build from node js and the domain is blabla.appspot.com ..
In 15 november, that domain direct to blabla.appspot-preview.com ..
So, i want to change the domain with custom domain, i have follow step by step, but my new custom domain are only directed to blabla.appspot-preview.com , not a primary domain.
Have suggestion for this case? I want to setup a custom domain for primary domain, not directed. 
Thank you.

NB : I have 2 domain in google domain and godaddy, both are same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic redirection google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091215/automatic-redirection-google-app-engine)

Comment: never heard of appspot-preview.com .... usually it's just appspot.com, how did you get that?

Comment: @LawrenceMok: it's specific to the new flex env, see duplicate comment.